# Restoring original fonts in windows 8.1 not working

Tags: fonts, windows, windows-8

I want to delete all fonts from my system (Windows 8.1 64 bit) except the original ones, and I followed the instructions (from many sites) to do so, but the fonts are not deleting at all. What I did (by the instructions) is:

1. > C:\Windows\Fonts
2. > Font settings
3. Clicking on the "restore default font settings" while "hide fonts base on language settings" selected (tried uncheck it too - same result).

I see no changes at all, all the fonts are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Change your font settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Change-your-font-settings) Microsoft article (applies to windows 8 as well).

Doing *Restore default font settings* does not change installed fonts, only removes any changes that you've made to your *display settings* (`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display`) including all manual changes that you've made to your display settings.

In other words:
*Restore default font settings* in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Fonts\Font settings` restores default data for values under this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
```

Example:

[image: WindowMetrics]

For instance, I have changed size of all items in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display` to *Medium - 125 %* for the sake of my old tired eyes:

```
==> reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" -v LogPixels

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
    LogPixels    REG_DWORD    0x78
```

while Windows default value is *Smaller - 100% (default)*:

```
==> reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI
    LogPixels    REG_DWORD    0x60
```

Indeed, `0x78` (decimal 120) is exactly 125 percent from `0x60` (decimal 96):

```
==> set /a 0x60 * 125 / 100
120
```